# Memory snapshot of .net core application in docker container

Tags: c#, .net, docker, memory-leaks

I have .net core application running in docker container in Linux. But it consumes a lot of memory. How can I get a memory snapshot of .net core application, to explore it?

Comment: Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/core/diagnostics/dotnet-gcdump, it can be used to create a memory-dump inside the Docker-Container.

Comment: @ChristophK can I get dump without installing tools in container? The problem is I have running docker container without installed tools inside it and I need a dump of memory of .net core app inside it